# Re-connect Eclipse project to new SVN repository

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

> I have a project checkout from SVN but now I have moved my SVN
>   repository to some other URL, but when I tried to disconnect project
>   from older SVN repo, it does but when I try to connect it, then it
>   recognize that this project has been previously connected to some SVN
>   and it's remembering older repository. How can I change it to new
>   repository? Without downloading project from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already disconnected, it's probably too late - at least if you had Eclipse delete the SVN metadata in the process. I think you'll have to check out again.

When you move the remote repository to a new URL, you should do the following in Eclipse:

- go to the svn respository exploring perspective
- select the svn URL that has changed from the "svn repositories" view
- right-click and choose "relocate"
- enter the new URL

(Assumes Subclipse. Subversive should have a similar feature.)

On the command line, that would be a "svn switch --relocate ..." command.